# How many exception instances are created

Tags: java, exception

I have a `methodA methodB methodC methodD` in `class A`

```
classA{

    methodA throws ExceptionA(){
        methodB 
    }

    methodB throws ExceptionA(){
    }
        methodC throws ExceptionA(){
            methodB
        }
        methodD throws ExceptionA(){
            methodC
        }
```

Lets assume My method D throws exception How many exception instances will be created?I am thinking since method level are stored in stack there will be 4 exception instances .Is my understanding right?

Comment: Does this code even compile?!

Comment: If noone calls the methods and no exceptions are being thrown, well, no exception will be thrown.

Comment: And he forgot the return values as well.

Comment: Is it mandatory to put syntax checked code here?I dont think so I am trying to understand concept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of exception instances created has nothing to do with throwing them. Instead, this number is the same as with each other object and can be obtained by counting how often the constructor of the respective exception class has been called.

Consider the following code snippet:

```
Exception a = new myException();
Exception b = new myException();
throw new myException();
```

This code creates 3 exception instances.

Comment: In my example my method d is throwing and it created 1 exception in its stack and method c has its own stack  like this 4 may be created?

Comment: @constantlearner I told you it has nothing to do with stacks or methods. Only the executions of "new ExceptionA()" counts.